# Quais exceções devo capturar em um try-catch?

Tags: java, android, exceção, try-catch

Tenho alguma dúvida em `try catch` em relação a quais tipos de exceções colocar. Nesse exemplo quer seria a melhor opção?

```
try {
    String folerPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Folder" + File.separator;
    File dir = new File(folderPath);
    deleteDirectory(dir);
} catch (Qual exceção?){

}
```

Comment: Eu dei uma editada na pergunta mas não sei se ela está muito clara. Parece que a resposta que você aceitou não responde ao que foi perguntado de fato. Você poderia esclarecer o que de fato você queria saber? Até porque esta resposta não responde nada de fato e no comentário dá um péssimo conselho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, caso precise tratar as exceções separadamente, aconselho usar try catch encadeado, segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
try {
// código

}catch (Excecao1 ex) {
//Tratamento da excecao 1
}

catch (Excecao2 ex) {
//Tratamento da excecao 2
}
```

Caso não precise tratar separadamente, apenas use o a classe genérica de exceções.

Comment: faço assim?: catch (Exception e){ e.getMessage(); }

Comment: Sim, caso queira mais informações use e.printStackTrace()

Comment: Ah, caso seu código lance apenas um tipo de exceção, utilize a classe da respectiva exceção.

Comment: Na verdade mesmo que lance mais um tipo de exceção deve-se tomar cuidado para não capturar a exceção genérica `Exception`, que pode mascarar erros não previstos. Vide resposta do @bigown.

Answer (score 11):

Atenção! Esta forma não é a ideal mais. Consulte documentação sobre.

Sempre olhe a documentação de todos os métodos usados para ver quais as possíveis exceções e decida quais você pode tratar de forma eficaz, ou seja, consiga resolver o problema.

[`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) indica que não gera exceção.

`File()` pode gerar um `NullPointerException` porém isto é erro de programação e não deve ser tratado de forma específica. Não tem nada que pode ser feito para resolver isto em tempo de execução, só arrumar o programa.

`deleteDirectory()` parece ser algo do seu código, então ter que ver dentro dele o que pode gerar exceções.

Eu não usaria um `try-catch` aí, mas provavelmente usaria dentro deste `deleteDirectory()`. Ali provavelmente tem outros tipos erros que podem ser importantes serem tratados.

Em um contexto maior do código eu poderia mudar de ideia e dizer que tem que tratar exceções mais genéricas. Em geral não se deve fazer isto em códigos específicos mas pode haver caso. É quase certo que **não** deve fazer isto aí mas há caso que capturar uma `Exception` geral pode ser útil.

Na verdade há um abuso generalizado no uso de `try-catch`, a maioria dos existentes em códigos não são necessários, alguns prejudicam o funcionamento da aplicação ou pelo menos a detecção de problemas. Em geral as pessoas usam achando que isto resolve problemas existentes quando na verdade só esconde eles. Outras vezes usam porque acham que deve ser usado sem saber porque.

Eu falo sobre isso em [diversas respostas aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D). Leia tudo o que puder sobre o assunto, mesmo que não seja sobre Java ou Android. Não só o que eu escrevi e o material encontrado aqui no site. É importantíssimo saber usar isto corretamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).