# Retorno do catch código limpo

Tags: java, exceção, estilo-de-codificação

Estou lendo o livro Código Limpo da série de Robert C. Martin. E foi apresentado uma situação muito comum no meu dia a dia.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nome = null;

    try {
        if (nome.length() > 10) {
            System.out.println("Nome maior que 10 caracteres");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nome menor que 10 caracteres");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Não encontro o registro no banco de dados
    }

}
```

Por vezes realizamos alguma operação que a exceção é inevitável. Neste código por exemplo, ao acontecer a exceção no `nome.length()` eu quero que o erro seja ignorado.

Deixo o comentário para descrever a razão do erro? Tiro o comentário? Ou podemos trabalhar como outra abordagem?

Lembrando que não quero gerar uma exceção!

Comment: Essa exceção do exemplo não é inevitavel. NullPointerException deve ser tratado sempre que possivel, até por ser simples seu tratamento. Se não quer gerar exceção, trate o erro.

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais exceções devo capturar em um try-catch?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86405/28595)

Comment: Relacionada²:[Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/28595)

Comment: Relacionada³:[Qual o melhor método para exceções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88923/28595)

Comment: O correto seria você fazer um tratamento para a exceção, por exemplo colocando um comentário. xD

Comment: @Articuno posso tratar o erro utilizando throws ou try catch. Qual seria sua abordagem para evitar o catch sem conteúdo?

Comment: Dá uma lida nas respostas das 3 perguntas que linkei, todas tratam deste mesmo tema, e há bastante dicas e esclarecimentos sobre esse assunto.

Comment: Ótimo. Irei fazer isso! @acklay uma frase que vi no livro muito boa é essa: "O uso de comentários é compensar nosso fracasso em nos expressar no código". Por esse motivo fiz a pergunta. hahahha

Comment: @acklay só deixar claro que isso é piada, tem gente que pode levar a sério.

Comment: @bigown mas tem um pouco de verdade, um código bem explicativo fala por si só e não precisaria dos comentários, mas os comentários são inevitáveis quando a implementação demanda alguma complexidade inerente da regra de negócio, nesse caso sendo adequados.

Comment: @Marlysson acho que você não entendeu a piada ;)

Comment: Apenas para complementar. Vi em um dos posts disponibilizados pelo @Articuno uma frase engraçada e muito boa que me orientou a respeito da minha pergunta: "Uma fada morre cada vez que um programador deixa um catch vazio"

Comment: @KaranAlvesPereira seu vontade de modificar o comentário do bloco `catch` com o seguinte texto: **fazendo um feericídio por deixar o bloco catch vazio**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um exemplo prático de como eliminar um tratamento de exceção e que simplifica o código e dá mais desempenho:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nome = null; //obviamente que é só para ilustrar, ninguém faria isto, certo?
    System.out.println(nome != null && nome.length() > 10 ? "Nome maior que 10 caracteres" : "Nome menor que 10 caracteres");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/ValidationNoException.java).

Pode se perguntar sobre o tratamento do erro do banco de dados. Isto não fazia nenhum sentido. Se tivesse algo que poderia causar um erro deste tipo seria o caso de capturar **esta exceção**, e não a `Exception`. Só trate as exceções que tem que tratar. Ou seja, não trate de outras, de exceções gerais, e não capture exceções que podem ser evitadas no código. O que pode ser evitado e não é pode ser considerado erro de programação e `try-catch` não serve para isso, corrija o erro no seu código.

Leia mais nos *links* apresentados nos comentários acima.