# O uso do Try no Delphi quando mal usado pode ser uma armadilha?

Tags: delphi, exceção, try-finally

Uma vez um programador viu meus códigos e elogiou por eu fazer uso do `Try`, confesso que não fiquei empolgado pelo elogio por achar que o uso do `Try` não é um modo simples de resolver exceções, vejo o uso de `Try`s indiscriminadamente até mesmo substituindo um `if` que poderia verificar as consistências do dados antes de qualquer execução, por exemplo:

```
try
  ...
  a := 1;
  b := 0;
  res := a / b;
except
  ...
  ShowMessage('Valor invalido'); // Nesse exemplo vamos ter que ficar caçando se o valor invalido é de a ou b
end;
```

Quando deveria ser:

```
  a := 1;
  b := 0;
  if (b <= 0) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Valor invalido');
  end
  else
  begin
    res := a / b;
  end;
```

Usando o `try` para capturar exceções ou destruir um objeto da memória (com `finally`) eu concordo plenamente a final muitas vezes não pensamos em todas possibilidades dentro de uma rotina, mas o uso do `try` de forma impensada pode trazer grandes dores de cabeça assim como o `with` opção do Delphi que eu me abstenho sempre que posso, não importa em ter que digitar mais.

Estou muito longe de ser doutor em programação digo que faço o que posso, graças a Deus tenho conseguido resolver os problemas me propostos, mas as vezes surgem alguns porquês na cabeça e precisamos levantar a questão diante dos amigos programadores para tornar a necessidade de uma função mais clara em nossa mente.

**Gostaria de saber a posição dos colegas quanto ao uso do `Try`.**

Comment: Qual o motivo de não usar o `with`? Não sei se o Delphi fez de um jeito que causa problemas.

Comment: Debuga um bloco com with e um sem, você vai ver a diferença. O problema está quando vai debugar, você não consegue ver os valores diretamente sem entrar no Evaluate / Modify, é uma boa opção pra economizar digitação, mas o debug se torna um fardo principalmente se tiver aninhados de with, se dois componentes tiver as mesmas propriedades dentro e o with tiver assim "with obj1, obj2 do" ixi, estou falando de mim ok, muitos gostam da praticidade que ele traz. Pra mim o with tem quase a mesma utilidade do "goto" muito usado antigamente (e o delphi tem goto e ninguém mais usa, que eu saiba, rs)

Comment: Não uso o Delphi, então não tem como :) Mas pelo que está dizendo é mal feito, aí concordo. O `with` deveria ser só *syntax sugar*, e só valido com identificadores de objetos já existentes com limitações em alguns tipos de métodos marcados devidamente para este fim.

Comment: Pois é o with no delphi tem sua utilidade, mas como é uma função livre ele é usado em tudo quanto é lugar por alguns programadores, por exemplo, na criação de um objeto poderia economizar alguma digitação, mas manipular as propriedades desses objetos com with, nossa vira um caos.

Comment: Acredito que o `Try` server para isolar um bloco de código onde algo "impreviso" pode ocorrer, como uma conexão com recurso externo. O que pode ser tratado, melhor tratar sem necessitar disparar um `exception`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De fato, dentro da minha observação, uns 90 a 99% dos programadores acham que o `try` resolve problemas, quando muitas vezes o que ocorre é o oposto.

Tem linguagens que tem uma cultura de uso de exceções, outras usam só quando é realmente útil. Não sei como é no Delphi, e costumo recomendar seguir a cultura da linguagem, na maioria das vezes. Mas também não pode fazer algo muito errado.

Ninguém vai morrer por usar exceções em excesso (talvez em uma aplicação médica :) ), mas o ideal é evitar exceções.

## Quando usar

- Eu não ligo muito quando a exceção é usada para indicar erro de programação, acho que deveria ser outra coisa, mas tá valendo. Só [se torna um problema quando o programador acha que deve capturar essa exceção achando que isso ajuda em alguma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86423/101). Claro que [capturar no geral para poder *logar* é ok](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101), mas isso só é necessário em um ponto da aplicação.
- Se o erro é catastrófico não adianta capturar o erro, você não pode fazer qualquer coisa útil.
- Se a API que você usa só permite detectar erros com exceção não tem muito o que fazer, tem que capturar para decidir o que fazer. Capturar a exceção específica sempre!
- Se detectar o problema para tomar uma decisão posterior que depende do estado anterior pode gerar uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), aí a exceção é uma boa.
- Se algo não deveria ocorrer, nunca, mas você sabe que pode ocorrer, a exceção foi criada justamente para isso, daí o nome dela. Em geral isso vem de algo externo a aplicação.
- Em alguns casos para simplificar o desenvolvimento pode-se abusar de exceção para indicar [fluxo normal, mas isso é errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101), se há uma chance razoável de dar errado, e esse razoável não precisa ser 50%, pode ser 1, 2 ou 3%, pode ser mais, ou menos, não tem número mágico, a exceção provavelmente é exagerada. Por isso [não costuma-se usar para validação e controle de fluxo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164502/101).

[Há casos que o código fica muito mais complicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128763/101). Exceção é um [`goto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101) que você não sabe para onde vai.

## Divisão por zero

O exemplo da pergunta é um erro de programação e não deve usar exceção. Use um `if` antes da operação para garantir que o divisor não é 0, portanto a segunda opção costuma ser melhor.

Não sei no Delphi a qualidade de implementação de exceções. [Seria bom fazer um teste (do jeito adequado) qual é mais rápido quando não existe a falha, quando tem pouco e muito também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17632/101).

Qual a chance do divisor ser 0? Se a resposta é "nunca deveria" ou "quase nunca", a exceção pode ser mais interessante, se tiver uma implementação moderna que trabalha com uma tabela auxiliar de pontos de captura e não uma pilha onde há captura.

Se [sabe que terão alguns casos que é 0 mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141899/101), então tem boa chance que as execuções que dão erro sejam tão lentas, e o lançamento de exceção baseado em tabela de captura é absurdamente lento, é provável que a performance fique pior.

Se há alguma chance do divisor mudar durante o processamento (*multithreading*) também é melhor deixar o erro ocorrer para evitar a *race condition*.

Eu só usaria a captura da exceção nesse caso se realmente a performance for claramente muito boa em quase todos os casos de uso.

## Performance

Em pilha de captura tem custo mesmo que não lance a exceção, ao ponto que um `if` deve custar mais barato, até porque o `if` permite otimizações, o `try` as inibe. Mas o custo de lançamento é bem baixo, porém, maior que [indicar o erro de outra forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Teste a performance como um todo, porque o fato de inibir otimizações pode trazer degradações reais não perceptíveis em um teste muito específico.

> muitas vezes não pensamos em todas possibilidades dentro de uma rotina.

Esse é o problema, programar é o oposto disso. Provavelmente a dica que recebeu tem a ver com isto: "põe `try-except` e fique tranquilo que qualquer erro que você cometer dá pra disfarçar", o que inclusive esconde informações relevantes para ajudar resolver o problema.

Quando a pessoa [captura "para ficar tranquilo"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108490/101) provavelmente captura uma exceção mais geral, ou seja, não tem como saber nem o que fazer com aquilo. Muitas vezes executam algo que não faz o menor sentido porque ela capturou tudo, mas tratou com algo específico.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101).

[O que são Exceptions?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88831/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Pois é o try pode "mascarar" um erro e custar bem caro ao processador.